# Delete all hidden items on the entire page, after click input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Delete all hidden items on the entire page, after pressing input. Need after CLICK. Can I use this to get rid of extra fields when using a php handler later?

```
$('input[name="submit"]').find(':hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Did it work when you try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).find('input[type="hidden"]').remove()
```

OR

By Click:

```
# html
<input type="submit" value="remove entire hidden items"/>

# jquery
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
   $(document).find('input[type="hidden"]').remove()
})
```

Comment: Need all hidden or display:none remove